# TypeError: utils.endOfDay is not a function

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I am new in react, using material-ui date picker in my project , from the documentation [here](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation) . In this i am using moment.js

the following code in datetimepicker

```
    import React,{ useState }  from 'react';
    import MomentUtils from 'moment';
    import {
        DatePicker,
        TimePicker,
        DateTimePicker,
        MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
     } from "@material-ui/pickers";

    function DateTimePickers() {
         const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new 
            Date());

          return (
             <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
             <DatePicker value={selectedDate} onChange= 
              {handleDateChange} />
              <TimePicker value={selectedDate} onChange= 
               {handleDateChange} />
                <DateTimePicker value={selectedDate} onChange= 
              {handleDateChange} />
            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
          );
        }
    export default DateTimePickers;
```

but showing error

TypeError: utils.endOfDay is not a function
getComparisonMaxDate
node_modules/@material-ui/pickers/esm/_helpers/text-field-helper.js:23

```
  20 |     return date;
  21 |   }
  22 | 
> 23 |   return utils.endOfDay(date);
  24 | };
  25 | 
  26 | var getComparisonMinDate = function 
       getComparisonMinDate(utils, strictCompareDates, date) {
```

Thanks in advance . Help me out of this problem

Comment: use import moment from 'moment'; Please also add package.json file. It looks like an installation issue rather than code issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The import is wrong. It should be:

```
import MomentUtils from '@date-io/moment';
```

You can refer to working CodeSandbox demo:https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-h3ke7?fontsize=14

**Clarification:**

- date-io provides abstraction over common javascript date management libraries. date-io/moment is just one of them. [data-io GitHub](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/date-io)
- You must install both moment and data-io/moment
- Material-ui/pickers fully relies on data-io. You must install it if you want to use material-ui pickers. You can further read in [material-ui-pickers GitHub](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers)

Comment: but already installed moment   "moment": "^2.24.0", is MomentUtils not in this?

Comment: pls refer your documentation link, the import is mentioned there ,for `MomentUtils `

Comment: @ajeeshs - I couldn't find MomentUtils in moment docs. Even if it exists, it doesn't have some functions that material-ui-pickers relies on (such as endOfDay). data-io provides all the functions that material-ui-pickers need.

Comment: Yes :) i missed dat

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue in date picker documentation
https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation

install thie version npm i @date-io/moment@1.x moment